# Is it possible to reverse a linked list with a single statement within a loop?

Tags: java, data-structures

Assume we have

```
ListNode {
     ListNode next;
     int number;

     //gets sets
}
```

Is it possible to reverse the list using a loop with only one string whithin a loop?

Something like this:

```
for(...) {
// only one string of code (one statement)
}
```

One guy told me that it's possible but I don't understand how.
Can you help with that please? Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "one string of code"? A line? A statement? Something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think a statement

Comment: Are you sure you weren't just trolled by a Haskell programmer? (It's trivial to do this in Haskell with 1 line being the base case of empty list, and 1 line for all other cases)

Comment: @Ordous Even if trolling, still doable :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. It isn't pretty.

First, a toString method for ListNode to verify the answer. You can print `root` and `reverse(root)` to see the results work.

```
public String toString() {
    if (next != null) {
        return "" + num + " " + next.toString();
    }
    return "" + num;
}
```

#### In-Place Reversal

A zero-line answer that reverses in place:

```
static ListNode reverse(ListNode node) {
    ListNode headNode = null;
    ListNode previousNode = null;
    for (; node != null; previousNode = headNode, headNode = node, node = node.next, headNode.next = previousNode)
        ;
    return headNode;
}
```

Basically, a lot of node child swapping. We track the previous node so we can attach it to the head node, but we also have to track the next node for iteration.

#### Return a new reversed List

Now, the code golfy reverse method that returns a new set of Nodes in a reverse order.

```
static ListNode reverse(ListNode node) {
    ListNode headNode = null;
    ListNode followerNode = null;
    for (; node != null; node = node.next, followerNode = headNode) {
        (headNode = new ListNode(node.num)).next = followerNode;
    }
    return headNode;
}
```

Basically, these methods abuse many things about Java that you really shouldn't. We abuse the for loop by not using any integers for iteration. Then we abuse the increment section by including two lines of code for assignment.

Then singular line of code sets the `headNode` to a new `ListNode` of the value, and then sets its `next` to the previous `headNode`.

Practically speaking, it would take less effort to write it correctly than to write something that saves lines.

I mean, technically, if you really wanted to, you could put everything into the for loop iterator portion and get no lines, but in the spirit of trying to actually follow the prompt, only true assignments have been placed in the for loop.

That being said, it is customary coding convention that we **DO NOT stuff code into a for loop for execution to save a few lines.** In this day and age, the only real purpose for that is shortening down spacing in code golf.

*PS: in the future, if anyone tells you something is possible in Java you should probably ask them to explain it. Whether or not things are possible in Java is a superset of whether we should be doing it in Java.*

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much for your explanation. Is it possible to write it without addinional space (I mean without creating new ListNode each iteration)?

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky yes. I've updated the answer. In fact, it's prettier than the one-liner that duplicates. It's just a lot of swapping of node nexts around. Similar to swapping the values of a and b in Java requiring a third variable, only in this case we are swapping a and keeping track of b.